# Consulta Eloquent relacionada

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hola estoy intentando  obtener los datos de un 'cliente'

tengo 3 Tablas

```
|Cliente|Cliente_servicio|Servicios
```

En la tabla cliente pues tengo los datos de un cliente

En la tabla Cliente_servicio 
Tengo el IDcliente, IDservicio,Descripcion

en la tabla Servicio 
solo el ID y nombre del servicio

Mi relación la tengo Así del modelo Cliente esta así

```html
 public function clienteservicio()
 {
  return $this->HasMany(Clienteservicio::class);
 }
```

Del modelo Cliente_servicio

```html
 public function cliente()
 {
  return $this->belongsTo(Cliente::class,'cliente_id');
 }


 public function servicio()
 {

  return $this->belongsTo(Servicio::class,'servicio_id');
 }
```

Y finalmente de Servicio

```html
 public function Clienteservicio()
 {
  return $this->belongsTo(Clienteservicio::class);
 }
```

hasta ahora para ver los datos de un cliente me los muestra así,
pero donde dice Clienteservcio como podría  obtener el nombre al servicio al que pertence?

```html
=> App\Cliente {#2925
     id: 2,
     nick: "test",
     nombre: "kjsdjkfsjkd",
     apellidoP: "jksjdjfksjkd",
     apellidoM: "jksjdkfjsdjkf",
     vive: "sdfjksdjkfjksd",
     created_at: "2018-10-07 22:08:15",
     updated_at: "2018-10-07 22:08:15",
     Clienteservicio: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#2932
       all: [
         App\Clienteservicio {#2937
           id: 1,
           cliente_id: 2,
           servicio_id: 1,
           descripcion: "excelente",
           created_at: null,
           updated_at: null,
         },
         App\Clienteservicio {#2935
           id: 2,
           cliente_id: 2,
           servicio_id: 2,
           descripcion: "ok",
           created_at: null,
           updated_at: null,
         },
       ],
     },
   }
```

hasta ahora así es como hago mi consulta, estuve probando con tinker. pero no puedo obtener ese dato más que me interesa.

```html
$prueba = Cliente::With(['Clienteservicio'])
        ->where('nick','test')
        ->first();
```

posiblemente estén mal mis relaciones pero no logro entender.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esto, suponiendo que estas en laravel 5.*

```
Cliente.php
 public function service()
 {
    return $this->HasMany(App\Service);
 }
Service.php
public function cliente() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Cliente');
}

$services= Cliente::find($id)->service()->get();
$services[0]['descripcion'] // utiliza un foreach o un for
```

clientes que estan en un servicio

```
 $clients = Servicio::find($id)->cliente()->get();
 $servicesInclient[0]['nombre']
```

Si no tienes el id :

```
 $clients = Servicio::where('atributo','valor')->first()->cliente();
```

Answer (score 0):

Como no veo la estructura de tus tablas, te pondré un ejemplo que yo mismo hice y es de la siguiente manera:

> Group.php

```
public function group_days()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\GroupDay::class, 'idGroup');
}
```

> GroupDay.php

```
public function day()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Day::class, 'idDay');
}
```

> Day.php

```
public function group_days()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\GroupDay::class, 'idDay');
}
```

Y construimos nuestra consulta con Eloquent usando `->with()` con el fin de recuperar los modelos asociados para este caso utilice la siguiente query Eloquent:

```
$oGroup = AdmAcaGroup::where('id', '=', $id)->where('idStatus', '=', CStatus::$ACTIVO)
    ->with(array('adm_aca_group_days' => function ($query) {
        $query->select('adm_aca_group_day.idGroup', 'adm_c_day.name')
            ->join('adm_c_day', 'adm_aca_group_day.idDay', '=', 'adm_c_day.id');
    }));

dd($oGroup->first()->toJson());
```

Espero y te sirva.